# How to select devices used for windows idle detection?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management, joystick

In my Windows 10 system I have connected a X52 Pro joystick. It seems to signal activity to Windows because the idle time counter never exceeds few miliseconds (tested with IdleClock http://www.maxoutput.com/). That is why the PC never goes to sleep.

Is there any way to select or deactivate the devices that Windows uses to determine whether a user is idle? I would like to limit it to mouse and keyboard.

Thank you in advance

Jan

Comment: I wonder if you Un-tick the box in Device Manager for the joystick (power management tab), the one that says "allow this device to wake the computer" would do the trick.

Comment: @Moab Thanks, I tried that but oddly the option is disabled (greyed out).

Comment: All I can suggest is to update the joystick driver if there is one available.

Comment: Thanks @Moab. I installed the latest Saitek Beta drivers for Windows 10, and it solved some of my problems. But the main problem remains: The PC still does not go to sleep.   Any idea for a workaround (except for unplugging Joystick)?

Comment: unplugging seems to be the only solution I have found, [some discussion here](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3hda3b/has_anyone_else_noticed_that_their_computer_no/) near bottom of thread they discuss joysticks